# Porque datos no cambian en AngularJS(Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

He encontrado un código libre de una persona implementando un sistema crud.

¿Porque cuando intento modificar las visualizaciones, osea etiquetas h1 y cosas así, siguen igual?

Ejemplo:

```
<th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Salary</th>
```

Pues yo lo cambio a:

```
<th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Salario</th>
```

Cuando miro el programa sigue poniendo salary.

añado info

No tengo ningun $scope.Salary, pero doy otro dato estoy utilizando php tambien,en el controlador tengo esto para la parte de listado:

```
myApp.controller('empController', function($route,$scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $scope.getEmployees = function(){
        $http.get('../api/select.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.employees = response.data;
        });
donde data es igual a la consulta que he hecho a la base de datos vamos un select * from employee para que me guarde todos los datos.
```

Comment: Y en el `html` están imprimiendo así tal cual lo copiaste en tu pregunta?

Comment: Recien estoy aprendiendo Angular *(igual que usted)*; le comento, para la forma que lo usa debio primero "poner" la variable(s) en `$scope`; es decir `$scope.Salary` asignandole el valor `$scope.Salary=valor;`

Comment: Claro esque es lo que me extraña que en el html no me cambia, no estoy cambiando nada de las consultas.

Comment: ¿Ese código está en una plantilla de angular o en el código PHP? Si está en una plantilla HTML deberías limpiar la caché de tu navegador para ver la nueva versión (como solución más rápida). Si no adjuntas más código o dónde encaja ese código en el todo no podremos ayudarte más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo, tenia que limpiar la cache y se actualizo todo. Gracias a @ OscarGarcia